# Dojo, how to do onclick event on a DIV

Tags: javascript, dojo

There was a fade out sample in the internet..
http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/fadeOut?t=tundra

but i want to do something different..
i want people directly click on the text then the text will fade out.

in my code there is a div wrap the text

```
<div id='parentNode'>
    <div id='textDiv' onClick='whenClickAnyWhereWithinThisDiv_performFadeOut()'>
       <div id='iconDiv'/>
       <div id='messageDiv'/>
    </div>
<div>
```

Code as show below, what i want is, when people click anywhere within the textDiv,
then the whole textDiv will fade away..hmm.....why my code doesn`t work???

```
function whenClickAnyWhereWithinThisDiv_performFadeOut () {
    ...
    ...
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('textDiv'), "onClick", fadeOutAndRemove(parentNode, textDiv));
}
function fadeOutAndRemove (parent, currentDiv) {
    // just assume i can get the parent Node, and the current div, which will be textDiv       

    var objectId = currentDiv.getAttribute('id');
    dojo.style(objectId, "opacity", "1");
    var fadeArgs = {
        node: objectId,
        duration: 2000
    };
    dojo.fadeOut(fadeArgs).play();

    setTimeout(function() { parent.removeChild(currentDiv);}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think you can accomplish it with this:

**HTML**

```
 <div id='parentNode'> 
    <div id='textDiv'> 
      <div id='iconDiv'>this is icon div</div> 
      <div id='messageDiv'>this is message div</div> 
    </div> 
 <div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// do it when the DOM is loaded
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
  // attach on click to id="textDiv"
  dojo.query('#textDiv').onclick( function(evt) { 
    // 'this' is now the element clicked on (e.g. id="textDiv")
    var el = this; 
    // set opacity
    dojo.style(this, "opacity","1"); 
    // do fade out
    dojo.fadeOut({ 
      node: this, 
      duration: 2000, 
      // pass in an onEnd function ref that'll get run at end of animation
      onEnd: function() { 
        // get rid of it     
        dojo.query(el).orphan() 
      } 
    }).play() 
  });
});
```

The click will bubble up so it'll be caught by `textDiv.`

Here are some helpful links:

- [Dojo Animation quickstart](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/Animation)
- [dojo.byId vs. dijit.byId](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/05/06/jsid-dijitbyid-and-dojobyid/)

Let me know if I misunderstood your question and I'll update my answer.  Hope this helps.