# What is href=javascript:;

Tags: javascript

in a code which i am goin through there is a link has href=javascript:; in code.when it is clicked it opens a lightbox to show some msg with close button.how is it done.I think this uses dojo

Comment: Did these answers provide you with an answer to your issue?

Answer (score 11):

The code:

```
<a href="javascript:;">..</a>
```

will actually do nothing.  Generally this Nothing link allows some javascript code to use the onclick event instead.  The onclick event triggers the window which may be from django or jquery or wherever.

Answer (score 5):

**EDITED:**

i have just added this link that explane you **how dojo work with onlclik event**:

> - [Dojo, how to do onclick event on a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107190/dojo-how-to-do-onclick-event-on-a-div)

ok, just for the sake, all the answer here are good answer, in your particular case if you are using **Dojo**

the `<a href="javascript:;" >` simply **[`prevent your <a> tag to jump around when clicked`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924031/stop-javascript-onclick-page-jumping)** and of course have no action!

probably you have something like this in your code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="some" class="some_too" rel="some_too_too">
```

**Dojo** simply keep the `<a>` **id** OR **class** OR **rel** tags and execute the function!

Answer (score 4):

`href="javascript:somefunction();"` is just a way to point to a function of some javascript code.

You can also do:  `href="#" onclick="somefunction();return false;"`

Nothing really dojo about it.  All it does is call the function or javascript code.  It just tells the element to use javascript.

or `href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="somefunction();"` as stated already.

Comment: imho `return false;` is missing in the example with `href="#"`

Comment: You can also do: `href="#" onclick="sommefunction();"`

Comment: yeah, either will work, but yes, binaryLV is correct, it should return false, since there is no url specified.  Corrected this.  Cheers :)  Though you can specify `javascript:void(0);` and you won't need to worry about returning false from this.

Comment: And furthermore, it's `onclick` not `onClick` please make sure to use the correct attribute the way it is meant to be, otherwise, you'll get XHTML validation errors on your webpages.

Answer (score 2):

It's known as the *javascript pseudo-protocol*. It was designed to replace the contents of the document with a value calculated by JavaScript. It's best not to use it, for several reasons, including:

- If JavaScript is disabled, you have a link that goes nowhere
- If your JavaScript returns a value, the contents of the page will be replaced by that value

[More reasons why you shouldn't use it](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#javascriptURI)

Answer (score 1):

All this does is make a call to a Javascript function which executes some Javascript. Maybe posting the code as an example helps.

Comment: bit strange, normally the code is as david stated

<a href="#" onclick="somefunction();">yourlinktext</a> Is the  link showing as url or image? I know lightbox uses the 'rel' attribute on images to show a fancy lightbox effect and let an image popup

Comment: he probably has an addEventListener somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @teehoo Do these respond to href=javascript; then?

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="callFunction();">
```

Call callFunction() method onClick

this can also be used as foollows

```
<a href="javascript:callFunction();">


<a href="#" onClick="callFunction();">
```

this also call javascript callFunction() method but it adds # in your URL to Avoid this  Use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="callFunction();">
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this just indicates that your link is going to perform some javascript function. Usually you couple this by hooking up events on the link e.g. OnClick/OnMouseMove

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, it's a URL to a resource that's reachable via the "javascript" protocol, just like you can have "http:" or "ftp:". I don't know if it's an actual standard but most browsers understand that the URL must be fed to the JavaScript interpreter. So, in practice, you can use it to have JavaScript code that's triggered by a link, e.g.:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Hello!')">Say hello</a>
```

Of course, writing your JavaScript code inside HTML tags is neither clean nor mantainable. But the possibility exists.

What about `href="javascript:;"`? If you pay close attention, you'll realise that ";" is a JavaScript code snippet that, well, does nothing. That's the point. This is often used to have a link that points nowhere. The main purpose is that clicking on it triggers JavaScript code defined somewhere else (via onclick event handlers).

Last but not least, you often see stuff like `onclick="javascript:doStuff()"`. The `onclick` HTML attribute expects Javascript code, not a URL. In this situation, the `javascript:` prefix is totally superfluous. However, the code still runs. It happens to be a label in JavaScript syntax just by chance ;-)